# How to override SupportedInterfaceOrientations (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, overriding, uiinterfaceorientation

My code for Portrait/Upsidedown orientations is:

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
     return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

`SLComposeViewController` does not override `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and so it inherits the default implementation from `UIViewController` which returns `UIInterfaceOrientationsMaskAllButUpsideDown` for iPhone.

I created a subclass of `SLComposeViewController`, but now how do I override `supportedInterfaceOrientations`?

Comment: The code you posted is how you override the method.

Comment: No, this is my original code, I need to know what code to put in subclass of SLComposeViewController so I can make SLComposeViewController flip to UpsideDown orientation. Currently, it doesn't.

Comment: Right, as I said, that is the code you need. Just add that method, as-is, to your subclass.

Comment: I did that already, that solved nothing.